# RecyclerView with nested setOnClickListener in a quiz based app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-viewholder

I have an issue with the implementation of a basic functionality of a quiz based application. Briefly, I have "questions" and "answers" in an `ArrayList<Question>` (each `Question` has its own `ArrayList<Answer>`, **3** for this example) that I used to populate an adapter of a `RecyclerView` in a fragment managed with MVVM.

This is my `onBindViewHolder` function:

```
  ...
  
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {        
 
  ...

    val curQuest = myDataset[position]    
    val shuffledAnswers = curQuest.answers


    holder.ans1.text = shuffledAnswers[0].answer_text
    holder.ans1.setOnClickListener {
        it.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.selected_ans_quiz)
        holder.ans2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
        holder.ans3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
    }

    holder.ans2.text = shuffledAnswers[1].answer_text
    holder.ans2.setOnClickListener {
        it.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.selected_ans_quiz)
        holder.ans1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
        holder.ans3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
    }

    holder.ans3.text = shuffledAnswers[2].answer_text
    holder.ans3.setOnClickListener {
        it.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.selected_ans_quiz)
        holder.ans2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
        holder.ans1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
    }
 }
```

Everything works well but the selection of the answer: if I select an answer of the first question (`myDataset[0]`), the view changes also for the **N+0** element in the list, where **N** is the max chunck of items loaded by the `RecyclerView`

How can I set the right attributes in a `RecyclerView` for each sub-element without propagation after the N*th* element loaded by `onBindViewHolder`?

Can it be fixed or should I have to change the implementation way?

EDIT: I just tried an alternative but with the same result, using an interface:

`QuizAdapter.kt`

```
  ...
  
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {        
 
  ...

    val curQuest = myDataset[position]    
    val shuffledAnswers = curQuest.answers


    holder.ans1.text = shuffledAnswers[0].answer_text
    holder.ans1.setOnClickListener {
        mCallback.onClick(shuffledAnswers[0],position,it,holder.ans2,holder.ans3)
    }

    holder.ans2.text = shuffledAnswers[1].answer_text
    holder.ans2.setOnClickListener {
        mCallback.onClick(shuffledAnswers[1],position,it,holder.ans1,holder.ans3)
    }

    holder.ans3.text = shuffledAnswers[2].answer_text
    holder.ans3.setOnClickListener {
        mCallback.onClick(shuffledAnswers[2],position,it,holder.ans2,holder.ans1)
 }

 interface OnItemClickListener{
      fun onClick(answerSelected: Answer?, questPosition: Int, selectedItemView: View, firstItemView: View, secondItemView: View)
 }
```

`QuizFragment.kt`

```
...

        mAdapter = QuizAdapter(this)
        listQuestions.apply {
            setHasFixedSize(true)
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
            adapter = mAdapter
            itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
        }
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : QuizAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
            override fun onClick(answerSelected: Answer?,
                                 questPosition: Int,
                                 selectedItemView: View,
                                 firstItemView: View,
                                 secondItemView: View) {
                Snackbar.make(selectedItemView, "Your answer for $questPosition is ${answerSelected!!.isCorrect}.",
                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show()
                selectedItemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.selected_ans_quiz)
                firstItemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
                secondItemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
                quizViewModel.chosenAnswers[questPosition] = answerSelected
            }
        })

        fab_endQuiz.setOnClickListener { view ->
            Snackbar.make(view, quizViewModel.chosenAnswers.toString(), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show()
            //parentFragment?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_quizFragment_to_nav_home)
        }
```

As you can see, with a FAB I can test the correctness of the selected answers and it seems ok, the map is filled with the user choices, even if there's a change in selection (map position, representing the question, is modified correctly).
But background colors remain mixed in different positions (the current ones visible in the RecyclerView plus others ahead), as said before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can be useful, I found a solution.
I added a boolean value to `Answer` class so that the `RecyclerView` has to check that when builds its list in xml, mixing to what I've done before

`QuizAdapter.kt`

```
  ...
  
  override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {        
 
  ...

    val curQuest = myDataset[position]    
    val shuffledAnswers = curQuest.answers


    holder.ans1.text = shuffledAnswers[0].answer_text
    if(shuffledAnswers[0].isSelected)
        holder.ans1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.selected_ans_quiz)
    else
        holder.ans1.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
    holder.ans1.setOnClickListener {
        shuffledAnswers[0].isSelected = true
        shuffledAnswers[1].isSelected = false
        shuffledAnswers[2].isSelected = false
        mCallback.onClick(shuffledAnswers[0],position,it,holder.ans2,holder.ans3)
    }

    holder.ans2.text = shuffledAnswers[1].answer_text
    if(shuffledAnswers[1].isSelected)
        holder.ans2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.selected_ans_quiz)
    else
        holder.ans2.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
    holder.ans2.setOnClickListener {
        shuffledAnswers[0].isSelected = false
        shuffledAnswers[1].isSelected = true
        shuffledAnswers[2].isSelected = false
        mCallback.onClick(shuffledAnswers[1],position,it,holder.ans1,holder.ans3)
    }

    holder.ans3.text = shuffledAnswers[2].answer_text
    if(shuffledAnswers[2].isSelected)
        holder.ans3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.selected_ans_quiz)
    else
        holder.ans3.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(parentFragment.requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
    holder.ans3.setOnClickListener {
        shuffledAnswers[0].isSelected = false
        shuffledAnswers[1].isSelected = false
        shuffledAnswers[2].isSelected = true
        mCallback.onClick(shuffledAnswers[2],position,it,holder.ans1,holder.ans2)
    }
 }

 interface OnItemClickListener{
      fun onClick(answerSelected: Answer?, questPosition: Int, selectedItemView: View, firstItemView: View, secondItemView: View)
 }
```

`QuizFragment.kt`

```
        mAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : QuizAdapter.OnItemClickListener{
            override fun onClick(answerSelected: Answer?,
                                 questPosition: Int,
                                 selectedItemView: View,
                                 firstItemView: View,
                                 secondItemView: View) {

                selectedItemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.selected_ans_quiz)
                firstItemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
                secondItemView.background = ContextCompat.getDrawable(requireContext(),R.drawable.default_ans_quiz)
                quizViewModel.chosenAnswers[questPosition] = answerSelected
            }
        })
```